# how to store multiple images store in Array and on single ImageView using volley

Tags: android, json, imageview, android-volley, response

I just want to put multiple photos in a single `imageView` using the `volley` that is going to change/blinks automatically every 3 seconds. it is not `ViewPager/slider`.

```
int[] imageArray;
ImageView blinkImage;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container,false);
    blinkImage=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.hardImage);
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        int i = 0;
        public void run() {
            blinkImage.setImageResource(imageArray[i]);
            i++;
            if (i > imageArray.length - 1) { i = 0; }handler.postDelayed(this,3000);
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(runnable,200);

        return view;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use rotateImage function with a handler to determine the interval

```
private ImageView image1;
    private int[] imageArray;
    private int currentIndex;
    private int startIndex;
    private int endIndex;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        image1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        imageArray = new int[8];
        imageArray[0] = R.drawable.one;
        imageArray[1] = R.drawable.two;
        imageArray[2] = R.drawable.three;
        imageArray[3] = R.drawable.four;
        imageArray[4] = R.drawable.five;
        imageArray[5] = R.drawable.six;
        imageArray[6] = R.drawable.seven;
        imageArray[7] = R.drawable.eight;

        startIndex = 0;
        endIndex = 7;
        nextImage();


    }

    public void nextImage(){
        image1.setImageResource(imageArray[currentIndex]);
        Animation rotateimage = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.custom_anim);
        image1.startAnimation(rotateimage);
        currentIndex++;
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(currentIndex>endIndex){
                    currentIndex--;
                    previousImage();
                }else{
                    nextImage();
                }

            }
        },1000); // here 1000(1 second) interval to change from current  to next image  

    }
    public void previousImage(){
        image1.setImageResource(imageArray[currentIndex]);
        Animation rotateimage = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.custom_anim);
        image1.startAnimation(rotateimage);
        currentIndex--;
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(currentIndex<startIndex){
                    currentIndex++;
                    nextImage();
                }else{
                    previousImage(); // here 1000(1 second) interval to change from current  to previous image 
                }
            }
        },1000);

    }
```

or you can build a custom frame animation like this

```
AnimationDrawable animation = new AnimationDrawable();
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image1), 100);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image2), 500);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image3), 300);
    animation.setOneShot(false);

    ImageView imageAnim =  (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
    imageAnim.setBackgroundDrawable(animation);

    // start the animation!
    animation.start()
```

Comment: Tanvir, But in this I do not want to be use handler, I want to work with the volley, get images by the server GET API.

Comment: Parveen in this case you may use second approach.just add your volley returned images into animation.addFrame() method. thats all you need to do.

Comment: TanvirChowdhury- can you share with me some code for that.

Comment: Try to use this in post execute method where you receive the image from volley AnimationDrawable animation = new AnimationDrawable();
 Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        int i = 0;
        public void run() {
            animation.addFrame(imageArray[i]), 200);
            ImageView imageAnim =  (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
      imageAnim.setBackgroundDrawable(animation);
      animation.start()
            i++;
            if (i > imageArray.length - 1) { i = 0; }
            handler.postDelayed(this,3000);
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(runnable,200);